# Joining two large disk .txt files on ID number if they are separated by newline character?

Tags: python, file, newline, large-files, txt

I need to get this result:

**Example input:** (two files)

Adam 1234

John 4321

Anderson 4321

Smith 1234

**Expected output:**

Adam Smith 1234

John Anderson 4321

My code for now works like this, it combines two .txt files... but I can't figure out how to combine them on the same ID?

```
    new = []
    with open('full.txt', 'w') as new_file:
        with open('1.txt') as fp_first_name:
            with open('2.txt') as fp_last_name:
                for line1 in fp_first_name:
                    for line2 in fp_last_name:
                        new_file.write(line1[:len(line1[-5:])] + line2)
```

I've tried like

```
if line2[-5:] == line1[-5:]:
new_file.write(line1[:len(line1[-5:])] + line2)
```

but this of course only takes first line of each "line2" and "line1", it doesn't go through a whole .txt file which it needs to do.

Comment: Why is it Adam Smith and not Smith Adam? Ah, ok, got it: You have two input files.

Comment: Are the IDs always 4 digits?

Comment: Yes, they are always 4 digits.

Comment: Btw, you can do this in the shell with *"join"* like this `join -j2 <(sort -g -k2 file1) <(sort -g -k2 file2)`

Comment: My file is large, meaning everything has to be after the for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the line and have the name and number for each line then compare and combine in case it is a match:

```
name1, number1 = line1.split(" ")
name2, number2 = line2.split(" ")
if number2 == number1:
    new_file.write(f"{name1} {name2} {number2}")
```

new code:

```
new = []
with open('full.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    with open('file1.txt') as fp_first_name:
        for line1 in fp_first_name:
            with open('file2.txt') as fp_last_name:
                for line2 in fp_last_name:
#                    print(f"L1: {line1}L2: {line2}")
                    name1, number1 = line1.split(" ")
                    name2, number2 = line2.split(" ")
#                    print(f"what {name1} {number1} {name2} {number2}")
                    if number2.strip() == number1.strip():
                        new_file.write(f"{name1} {name2} {number2}")
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't do the trick, nothing is in output in the "new_file".

Comment: my mistake, but corrected your code also... check now

Comment: This does. And I've added `+ '\n'` in the write function so it goes to the next row every time. 

Could you please explain why does it work when we place `for line1 in fp_first_name:` right after the `with open('file1.txt') as fp_first_name:`?

Comment: And also, what does f in the `new_file.write(f"{name1} {name2} {number2}"` do?

Comment: f"{name1} {name2} {number2}" is as "{} {} {}".format(name1,name2,number2) it is a python format method: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp, very useful in formatting strings, which will convert even ints/floats to string based on a specified format...

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain also why does the code works when we place `for line1 in fp_first_name:` right after the `with open('file1.txt') as fp_first_name:` and does not work in my case, after last `with open()` statement?

Comment: because in your case you iterate only once through the second file... in my case I iterate for each line in the first file.